# unable to generate SAML metadata file

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-saml, adfs2.0

I'm using AngularJS and spring security in a web application. We were using the basic authentication and now we are trying to put in place SAML for SSO login.
As we are using Java based annotation I tried to follow this [example](https://github.com/koldovsky/kids-room), I just added the [securityConfig](https://github.com/koldovsky/kids-room/blob/master/src/main/java/ua/softserveinc/tc/config/SecurityConfig.java) part to my application with also [loadUserBySAML](https://github.com/koldovsky/kids-room/blob/master/src/main/java/ua/softserveinc/tc/service/impl/SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl.java) service. I also configured my ADFS service in active directory and generated the federationmetadata.xml file, however, I wasn't able to generate the metadata.xml file.
When I try http://localhost:8080/myapp/saml/metadata I get 404 not found.
I'm sure that I've missed something, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the spring_saml_metadata.xml file directly from this [link](https://saml-federation.appspot.com/saml/web/metadata/generate?).
You can try this [example](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) with Java based configuration, just follow those [steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html)   , and then you will get a working java based configuration for SAML and ADFS.